# Mathematica recursion, solve fixed point

Tags: recursion, wolfram-mathematica, recurrence, evaluate

Here's a simple question with hopefully a simple answer. (Disclaimer: I'm new to Mathematica.) I'm trying to find the fixed points of a difference equation. A simple example is:

```
x[t_] := x[t] = (x[t - 1])^2
Solve[x[t] == x[t - 1], x[t - 1]]
```

It outputs `$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded.` so I'm assuming it's recursively substituting `x[t]` and `x[t-1]` at the same time? I tried

```
Solve[x[t] == Hold[x[t - 1]], x[t - 1]]
```

but that didn't fix anything. If it would just substitute in `x[t-1]^2` for `x[t]`, it would see it's super easy to solve. Any suggestions on how to nudge Mathematica?

Comment: Hmm...if I try RSolve[x[t+1]==x[t],x[t],t], it still gives me the recursion depth error. Since this is only an example (my real problem is a system of equations, each of which is fairly complicated), I'd like to avoid writing out the equations explicitly in RSolve or Solve. Otherwise, I could just do Solve[x[t-1]=(x[t-1])^2,x[t-1]] since I'm just solving for the fixed points.

Comment: if you just define `x[t]` (no underscore and be sure to `Clear[x]`) you will get a solution w/o any recursion

Comment: @Bill, unfortunately I have noticed that problem and so I've been restarting constantly, but even when restarting with a new notebook I get the recursion depth error. Here's exactly what I typed:
`x[t_] := x[t] = (x[t - 1])^2`
`RSolve[x[t + 1] == x[t], x[t], t]`

Comment: @george, unfortunately, that's kind of the easy way out and doesn't really solve my problem since I will be doing other operations on x[t], such as taking derivatives and whatnot where I will actually want a t dependence rather than just a variable defined with the name "x[t]"..

Comment: @Bill, sorry for the misunderstanding. That doesn't really solve my problem though, since as I mentioned in my second comment "I'd like to avoid writing out the equations explicitly in RSolve or Solve." Thanks for you suggestions, though.

Comment: @Bill, thanks for your comment, although it was more of a "can Mathematica do this" vs a "how do I find the fixed point". I guess you don't know of a way to get it to work, which is fine, but I'd still be interested if someone else knows if there is a way. No need to get touchy.

Answer (score 0):

You have x[n+1] = x[n]^2.  If you just attack this as a recurrence, then you have an infinite recursion.  (What's your initial case?  You don't specify one, and you don't need it generically to find fixed points.  However, all M'ma knows is that you have some *syntactically* recursively defined function -- you evaluate the function by applying the SetDelayed[] that you've written.)

However, if you phrase this as "y[x_] := x^2" separating the update rewriting rule from the recursion rewriting rule, you can find fixed points via "y(x)=x":

```
Solve[y[x]==x,x]
```

In fact, this is the generic way of framing the problem of finding fixed points -- what is the input that when I act on it with the update function gives me the input back?

Suppose now you want k-periodic points...

```
kPoints[k_] := Solve[Nest[y,x,k]==x,x]
```